# How to delete completely the initial table in Android

Tags: android, database

I created a table with the name SONGS in the assets/folder. And after that I create a new project, my project run to create a database name "data" with table name "BOOKS". But I found that the table "SONGS" also created in my new database? And now my database have two table "BOOKS" and "SONGS". I don't know why? How can I delete completely the "SONGS" table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two recommendations:

1. Modify your program so it runs an SQL query that DROPs table SONGS
2. adb into your device/emulator, run `sqlite` and directly type in the DROP command

Comment: Thanks, Will!
1. I mean a way to delete table "Completely". I can delete the "SONGS" in my project, but how about another projects?
2. I don't know what's "adb into your device/emulator" ? How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

No. The `assets/` folder is baked into the APK, and the APK cannot be modified at runtime.

Comment: I have fix my question, maybe you can help me.